# SQL Query for counting the frequency of transactions based on balance changes

Tags: sql

I have a dataset containing transaction data of customers for investments  and here's a sample of the dataset:

| user_id | date | Invested_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 10/06/2021 | 100000 |
| 0001 | 10/07/2021 | 100000 |
| 0001 | 10/08/2021 | 300000 |
| 0001 | 10/09/2021 | 300000 |
| 0001 | 10/10/2021 | 400000 |
| 0002 | 10/06/2021 | 100000 |
| 0002 | 10/07/2021 | 100000 |
| 0002 | 10/08/2021 | 80000 |
| 0002 | 10/09/2021 | 80000 |
| 0002 | 10/10/2021 | 70000 |

If there's a positive change in the invested amount, then it's considered as buying while if there's a negative change then it's selling. I have two queries to make:

-Find the top 5 users with the most frequency on buying

-Find the top 5 users with the most frequency on selling who are male.

I was thinking of using Lag and Partition By for this problem to calculate the changes for each user id but I'm still confused on how you can count the frequency of the transactions especially as there are some days where the balances are the same.

Comment: Use `case` to return 1 when there's an increase, i.e. investment_amount > prev_investment_amount and sum() the results. Same thing for decreases. Then order by the sum() and take `limit 5`

Answer (score -1):

We can use a cursor to fetch each line and do the comparing job based on the current invested_amount and the previous invested_amount. If the new amount is greater than the old, increase the total buy count for the user. The whole job is done in a stored procedure.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists top_5_buyer//
create procedure top_5_buyer()
begin
declare old_uid int default 0;
declare old_amount int;
declare new_uid int ;
declare new_amount int;
declare sum_buy_count int;
declare fin bool default false;
declare c cursor for select user_id,invested_amount from investments order by user_id,`date`;
declare continue handler for not found set fin=true;
drop temporary table if exists t ;
create temporary table t (user_id int,user_sum_buy_count int);
open c;
lp:loop
    fetch c into new_uid ,new_amount;
    if fin=true then
        insert into  t values(old_uid,sum_buy_count); -- this is for the last user_id's sum_buy_count to be inserted
        leave lp;
    end if;
    if new_uid !=old_uid then
        if old_uid!=0 then
            insert into  t values(old_uid,sum_buy_count);
        end if;
        set old_uid=new_uid,old_amount=new_amount,sum_buy_count=0;
    end if;
    if new_amount> old_amount then
        set old_amount=new_amount,sum_buy_count=sum_buy_count+1;
    else 
        set old_amount=new_amount;
    end if;


end loop lp;
select * from t order by sum_buy_count desc limit 5;
end// 
call top_5_buyer//
```